# Switching UINavigationViewController to UITabBarController with Segues

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am changing my app to use `UITabBarController` instead of `UINavigationViewController`. I replaced controllers accordingly and app launches with tabs successfully. Later in the code I came across some difficulties using segues where lines like

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ImageViewController" sender:self];
```

won't work producing error

"**Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController**"

When I embedded `UINavigationController` into the initial `FirstViewController`, line above worked fine. I need that line to switch between views and pass some data to another view controller.

**The problem** is that using segue identifier to go to `SecondViewController` hides TabBar navigation (unless I wrap `SecondViewController` in `UINavigationController` again and so on). That is not the solution.

**Question**: How to use `UITabBarController` and still take advantage of segues while keeping tab navigation visible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController"

Sounds to me like you are using a `push` segue somewhere outside a navigation controller. Try to select all "segue bubbles" in interface builder that are **not** inside a navigation controller:

[image: Segue Bubble]

and check the segue's style in the right pane:

[image: Segue Settings]

If the style is set to the value `push` as shown above change it to `modal` or `custom`:

[image: Change style to Modal]

Comment: You are right. This actually resolves my problem with using segues on UITabBarController.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your connections. If you are using interface builder (storyboard) then your connections should look like this. See pic

Notice you are missing UINavigation Title headers. Also the gray area below on each view controller means that space is reserved for images for UITabBarController

Another problem is your UIToolBar. Looks like its sitting on top of where UITabBar will be displayed. That may/may not get your app rejected by apple since you already have a UINavigationController and UITabBarController. If you need more buttons/options on that page make them UIButtons instead.

[image]